# WatchKit Table flickering when updated

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am currently working on a watchkit app and ran into a problem with a flickering table.

The situation is as follows: With the storyboard tool, I created a table containing two row types.
The concept is, that when the data for the table is being downloaded, there is only one row of the first type which will use the whole space to indicate, that data is being downloaded. When the data arrives the second row type is used to display the data.

The problem is, that the table is somehow flickering, while it is being updated with the data. I was able to fix this problem by removing the download indication message und using only the one row type for data.

My question is, if someone did run into a similar problem or if there is any better way/pattern to display this kind of information messages, which show the user whats going on when he is using the app.

Comment: I ran into the same issue but it's not clear to me if it is just the simulator or if the flicker will happen on a real watch since I don't have one to test with yet... Have you been able to test it on a real watch? The only other option I could think of is to present a modal view while loading the data but that doesn't seem very elegant.

Comment: yeah especially because in my understanding users are able to dismiss these modal views

Comment: I have seen flickering on the simulator which does translate onto the watch. In fact, a possible solution which solved it in the simulator actually still flickers in the watch itself.

Answer (score 1):

The WatchKit Table will flicker when reloading when a visible cell is different size than the other cells. Make sure they are all the same height and width and you will not have a flicker.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to put a group above my table that took up the entire screen with a loading animation inside it. I then hide/show the groups as needed.

Comment: how would you put something over anything within the watchkit interface builder? I am only able to put things in groups or arrange things next to each other

Comment: I put the `WKInterfaceImage` in a `WKInterfaceGroup` positioned at the top of the view, with the `WKInterfaceTable` below it. I then set the group/image to size to fit the entire view. That way, when I show it, it completely pushes the table out of sight and won't scroll.